# How Can I convert a csv into json network diagram file for display with sigma.js

Tags: php, mysql, json, diagram, sigma.js

I am researching whether I can generate network diagrams using sigma.js (or equivalent) from a tabular dataset, (in MYSQL). From my research it appears that the json format for sigma.js needs an x,y and size value for each node whcih suggests that the 'diagram' ie. the relative x & y positions and size is already set.

I am completely unfamiliar prior to this with network diagrams but it appears that the missing link between sigma.js and my data is the generation of this x,y,size, data. generating the json from php once I have these variables would obviously be a trivial matter but I have no idea how I can do this and google hasn't yielded any libraries. There are standalone applications but that is no good because it needs to sit in a web app.

It's probably that I don't know what to search for to find what I need.

Does anyone know how I could generate this kind of network diagram information in php or provide any pointers?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gephi application. It has the option to import csv file containing the node and edge data and then view and adjust your network. After that you could export the network in json format by installing an appropriate gephi plugin. This json file can be used by sigma js web application